# How to open android Camera with Chaquopy and openCV?

Tags: python, android, opencv, camera, chaquopy

I execute python code for an image recognition task and it works very well but when I implement it into an android application using Chaquopy it dosn't work. This is because the first insruction in the python code aims to open the camera using this insruction cap = cv2.videoCapture(0) and this instruction dosn't work on the android device.
I have also added camera and storage permissions in the androidManifest.xml
This is my Java code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (! Python.isStarted()) {
        Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(this));
    }

    Python py = Python.getInstance();
    PyObject pym =py.getModule("MyPythonClass");

}
```

and this is the python code (the name of the class is MyPythonClass.py) :

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import pyramid_gaussian
from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression
import imutils
from skimage.feature import hog
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from skimage import color
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import glob
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils.video import FPS
import numpy as np
import argparse
import time
import cv2

min_wdw_sz = [68, 124]
step_size = [10, 10]
orientations = 9
pixels_per_cell = [6, 6]
cells_per_block = [2, 2]
visualize = False
normalize = True

threshold = .3
clf = joblib.load(os.path.join('/storage/emulated/0/Download/', 'svm.model'))
def sliding_window(image, window_size, step_size):

    for y in range(0, image.shape[0], step_size[1]):
        for x in range(0, image.shape[1], step_size[0]):
            yield (x, y, image[y: y + window_size[1], x: x + window_size[0]])
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture (0)

# loop over the frames from the video stream
while True:

    ret, frame = webcam.read()

    im = imutils.resize(frame, width=min(300, frame.shape[1]))
    orig = im.copy()
    min_wdw_sz = (64, 128)
    step_size = (10, 10)
    downscale = 1.25
    #List to store the detections
    detections = []
    #The current scale of the image
    scale = 0

    for im_scaled in pyramid_gaussian(im, downscale = downscale):
        #The list contains detections at the current scale
        if im_scaled.shape[0] < min_wdw_sz[1] or im_scaled.shape[1] < min_wdw_sz[0]:
            break
        for (x, y, im_window) in sliding_window(im_scaled, min_wdw_sz, step_size):
            if im_window.shape[0] != min_wdw_sz[1] or im_window.shape[1] != min_wdw_sz[0]:
                continue
            im_window = color.rgb2gray(im_window)
            fd = hog(im_window, orientations, pixels_per_cell, cells_per_block, transform_sqrt=normalize)

            fd = fd.reshape(1, -1)
            pred = clf.predict(fd)

            if pred == 1:

                if clf.decision_function(fd) > 1:
                    detections.append((int(x * (downscale**scale)), int(y * (downscale**scale)), clf.decision_function(fd),
                                       int(min_wdw_sz[0] * (downscale**scale)),
                                       int(min_wdw_sz[1] * (downscale**scale))))



        scale += 1

    clone = im.copy()

    # loop over the detections
    for (x_tl, y_tl, _, w, h) in detections:
        cv2.rectangle(im, (x_tl, y_tl), (x_tl + w, y_tl + h), (0, 255, 0), thickness = 2)

    rects = np.array([[x, y, x + w, y + h] for (x, y, _, w, h) in detections])
    sc = [score[0] for (x, y, score, w, h) in detections]

    sc = np.array(sc)
    pick = non_max_suppression(rects, probs = sc, overlapThresh = 0.3)
    #  print "shape, ", pick.shape

    for(xA, yA, xB, yB) in pick:
        cv2.rectangle(clone, (xA, yA), (xB, yB), (0, 45, 255), 2)



    # show the output frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", clone)
```

and this is what error the logact shows :

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com........MainActivity}: com.chaquo.python.PyException: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: com.chaquo.python.PyException: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
        at <python>.<module>(/android_asset/chaquopy/app.zip/MyPythonClass.py:44)
```

EDIT :

permissions (storage and camera) are granted in the phone.
and the : minSdkVersion  19
          targetSdkVersion 28
          compileSdkVersion 28

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Did you get any exception or error message in the logcat? If so, please add it to the question.

Comment: @mhsmith the above code dosn't show any thing (no camera is open and then no frame to detect), I will put the entire code of the python class and what the logcat shows

Comment: @mhsmith I have added all the python code an logcat errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think OpenCV has some support for the native Android camera API, but it apparently doesn't work in the current Chaquopy build. As you've found in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57641801), the easiest workaround is to capture the image in Java and then transfer it to Python as a byte array.